# VueJS application with History Mode in AWS EC2 IIS

Tags: amazon-ec2, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJS application that I'm publishing into a EC2 IIS Server.

The problem that I have is that `History Mode` is not working on the EC2 IIS instance. So when I refresh the application I get a 404 Error because the resource is not found.

I have the `web.config` in the root of the application as it states in the Vue website, but I still have the same problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In my local IIS works fine, so I don't know if this is something about EC2 or anything else.

Comment: Did you install IIS Rewrite?

Comment: Yes is already installed. Works locally but in EC2 is not working

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't find the solution, it works if I access anything other than the root, www.domain.com/something accessing www.domain.com doesn't work.

Comment: @DarkDucke I ended up running it on NodeJS instead of IIS.